# Confusion on whether to use a statistical test

Tags: statistics

I'm currently doing a data science project using UK government COVID infection and deaths data from local authority districts. I'm looking to answer whether age of an area has an affect on COVID infections and deaths. Do younger areas have increased cases than an older area as younger people are out and about more?

I've arranged the data into different median age groups, i.e. one age group 30-35 with the COVID case and deaths data from local authorities with a median age between 30 and 35, one for 35-40, one for 40-45 etc.

My aim is to see if the COVID case data is different between these age groups, and so statistically significant. I've researched that the best test for this is one-way ANOVA.

I'm wondering this however: arent statistical tests only needed for sample data to infer information about the population? Given I have data from the whole population of the UK, shall I not just directly compare group means? I'm rather confused and the wealth of data isn't helping! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: “Population” gets used in introductory statistics classes instead of defining and using random variables. Much of the time, the “population” under study is more like a “data-generating process” than a collection of people or widgets. Thus, you might be more interested in the data-generating process than the collection of people in the United Kingdom. (But only the investigator can decide that!)

Comment: Thanks, I see your point! I guess positive tests could have been missed in the data generating process and thus the data wont be indicative of the whole population. Got confused with the wealth of data but nice to get my head wrapped around it! I was wondering, the case data isn't THAT normally distributed with a few rare instances skewing the data. Is it best to remove these instances, transform the data or just perform a non parametric test?